# Setting ProhibitDTD property using IXMLDOmDocument pointer

Tags: c++, ixmldomdocument

I am using `IXMLDomDocument` pointer to load my XML. the load fails saying DTD is prohibited. Could not find a function to set `ProhibitDTD` property.

example:

```
IXMLDOMDocument *pXMLDom = NULL;
CreateAndInitDOM(&pXMLDom);
{
   //succeeds
}
pXMLDom->load(varFileName, &varStatus);
{
   //fails: DTD is prohibited
}
```

I cannot find any function to set this property.
How can I set this property to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either `IXMLDOMDocument2` or `IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr`.